# On change even handlers for a datepicker on a dynamically inserted input tag doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have two dynamically inserted  tags with IDs *pick-from* and *pick-to*. I am using this plugin: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ to call a datepicker when it is clicked and perform some tasks when the date changes. It used to work when the input tags were not dynamically inserted but the application behavior had to be changed and now, the input tags are dynamically inserted. The code below no longer works:

```
var picker = $('#pick-from, #pick-to').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        picker.datepicker('hide');

        var today   = new Date(ev.date),
            dd      = today.getDate(),
            mm      = today.getMonth() + 1,
            yyyy    = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
        if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

        var inputVal    = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy,
            target      = ev.currentTarget.id;

        // All my other code goes here.
    });
```

I even tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pick-from, #pick-to', function() {
    var picker = $(this).datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        picker.datepicker('hide');

        var today   = new Date(ev.date),
            dd      = today.getDate(),
            mm      = today.getMonth() + 1,
            yyyy    = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
        if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

        var inputVal    = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy,
            target      = ev.currentTarget.id;

        // A lot of other code comes here.
    }});
```

The second code snippet works but not consistently. It works when I click on both input boxes and click on either one for the second time. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the event to the container element and delegate it:

```
$("#myContainer").on('changeDate', '#pick-from, #pick-to', function() { ... });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What line did you want me to replace?

Comment: You will have to change the event binding on your first example. Move the event to a call like I've showed above: `var picker = $('#pick-from, #pick-to').datepicker(); // stop this line here`. Make a new line with the example I gave you.